# Warning: Mutate_impl(.data, dots): Unequal factor levels: coercing to character

Tags: r, warnings, dplyr

The Titanic Dataset can be downloaded from kaggle: kaggle.com/c/titanic/data. Please use the train.csv or install the package 'titanic' and use the dataset titanic_train.

This works

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

titanic <- titanic %>%
    mutate(Cabin_Letter = ifelse(!is.na(Cabin), str_extract(Cabin, "[A-Z]+"), 'Unknown'))
```

This does not work entirely

```
titanic <- titanic %>%
    mutate(Cabin_Letter = factor(ifelse(!is.na(Cabin), str_extract(Cabin, "[A-Z]+"), 'Unknown')))
```

Warning:

Warning messages:
1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
4: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
5: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
6: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
7: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector

How could I resolve this issue? I don't want to take the extra line:

```
titanic$Cabin_letter <- factor(titanic$Cabin_letter)
```

Comment: I could not find the `titanic` data frame in R. Please clarify how did you get this data if possible.

Comment: oh sorry, you can use the package 'titanic' or download from kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Comment: There are four datasets from the `titanic` R package. None of them called `titanic`. Could you make your example code reproducible by providing more information about the data?

Comment: I ran your code, use `titanic_train` as `titanic`, but I could not reproduce your warning message. The code seems to work fine.

Comment: @ycw I restarted my computer and R and you are right, I no longer get an error! Next time I will try this first before posting. Weird. Any idea why such simple fix does the trick or why such an error arises?

Answer (score 29):

This issue can happen if the data is grouped (`grouped_df`) using the `group_by()` function. I just ran into it. My solution was to `ungroup()` the data frame and then convert to factor using `as.factor()`.